# Using the SHIFT key in Terminal

Tags: command-line, keyboard, shortcut-keys

I am very new to Linux, please excuse me if this is a very simple question and point me to the things I need to read. But I've been unable to find an answer so far.

In Terminal, when I am trying to select the text in the command line by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Left</kbd> or <kbd>Right</kbd>, I get "D" and "C" typed instead. (<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Up</kbd> yields A and <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Down</kbd> B). I've read somewhere how to copy-paste using the mouse; I cannot imagine the Terminal doesn't provide for full keyboard control.

Note: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Left</kbd> or Right moves the cursor around as it should, but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Left</kbd> or <kbd>Right</kbd> still types D and C. Puzzled.

Comment: This is the expected behavior [for historical reasons](http://askubuntu.com/questions/284668/whats-the-history-about-the-shift-arrow-keys-in-terminal/284716#284716).

Comment: It's actually pretty interesting that the idea of using shift+arrow to select text never made its way into our terminal emulators. It never even occurred to me to try, but I think that's because cursor position and text selection are totally unrelated in the terminal. The closest equivalent I can think of would be binding shifted arrows to enter copy mode in tmux.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems to be a known bug - see here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vte/+bug/546021 and the upstream bug here https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=617646

Copy paste works with Ctrl-Shift-C and -V, respectively. Basically all relevant shortcuts you know from other Gnome applications can be applied in the terminal by adding an additional Shift- keypress... Ctrl-Shift-Q for quit, for example.

Comment: Sorry to hear this but thank you for the answer anyway.

Answer (score 2):

`screen` is a, well, it describes itself as a terminal multiplexer. It provides an enhanced terminal environment and includes a mechanism for text selection and copy/pasting using just keyboard. CTRL+[ lets you roam the buffer with a cursor. Press enter or space to start the selection, then again to finish the copy and exit roaming mode. CTRL+] pastes your selection.

Going this route (which I can't live without: GNU screen is one of the first things I install on any new computer), you find `byobu` less intimidating. Screen is a beast to configure, byobu makes it look beautiful.

`tmux` is another terminal multiplexer with similar functionality. Apparently it has a bunch of improvements over `screen`, not least of which is a sane configuration file.

Comment: Thanks for contributing. I hope still, that the simple terminal will function the way it should one day. It's impossible to understand that one should use a _mouse_ in the _terminal_!