# What's the history about the Shift + Arrow keys in terminal?

Tags: command-line

I'm wondering why  <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Arrow Key</kbd> result in one of the `A`, `B`, `C` or `D` letters.

Why not other letters? Why any letter at all?

Comment: Intriguing :D My bet? Has to do with text based gaming :D

Comment: Just an observation: in tty `Shift + Arrow Keys` doesn't do anything.

Comment: @Rinzwind: :)))

Comment: I asked this question on Unix/Linux Stack Exchange. There are some useful answers. Maybe you want to look at them. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/73669/what-are-the-characters-printed-when-altarrow-keys-are-pressed

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Terminal emulators such as `gnome-terminal` ("Terminal" in Ubuntu) but also `xterm` and `urxvt` are named "emulators" because they reproduce the behavior of older terminals which were the only display of a computer. Such terminals communicated with the computer with a text-based protocol and were initially designed to receive only text. Quickly, more control was needed: how to erase a line? Use colors? Or change the cursor position?

[image: VT-100 terminal]
<sup>Source: [The Art of Unix Usability - Command-Line Interfaces](http://www.catb.org/esr/writings/taouu/html/ch02s02.html)</sup>

Escape sequences were designed for every terminal to do such things. They are named *escape* because they start with the ASCII escape code: `33`. There's no way to print such a character directly, which makes it a good fit for such sequences. When we still want to display this characted, `^[[` is used, and this is what I'll use in my explanations.

When the terminal received `^[[A`, it did not mean "print ^[[A", but "the user pressed the up-arrow key". "A" here is totally arbitrary: it just happens to be the letter everybody agreed on, because that's what the DEC VT-52 and its successor the popular VT-100 terminal used.

[image: DEC VT-52 Maintenance Manuel 1976]

<sup>Source: DEC VT-52 Maintenance Manual 1976</sup>

This is still the way terminal emulators work today: depending on the `$TERM` variable, a database named `terminfo` is responsible for saying what codes should be sent to the shell (bash, sh, zsh...), which is then responsible for understanding them and react to them.

Now, the code for <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>up</kbd> happens to be `^[[1;2A`: the terminal emulator sends this code to the shell, which tries to interpret `^[[1;2` but does not display anything because it doesn't know about that escape sequence. But `A` is left and displayed.

Comment: Wow, interesting. Now all those `^[[A` make sense when I click the arrow keys while a process is running on the terminal.

Comment: You may hit CTRL-v just before you hit SHIFT-UpArrow to 'view' the escape sequences in raw form. Unless you have changed the defaults, ESC should appear on your terminal screen as ^[

Comment: @arielf You can also run `cat >/dev/null` then type, and press Ctrl+C (or Enter then Ctrl+D) when done.